# Is there anything simpler than FTP for sending files between Linux machines?

Tags: linux, ftp, file-transfer

I need to transfer files from one CentOS server to another. I'll transfer 5MB files about every 10 minutes. I do not need encryption.

What is an easy way for a fast transfer of those files? Is there something simpler than FTP?

Comment: you should rephrase 'simpler' in a way that describes what kind of problem you have with ftp or with your current setup. and if your files are 5MB in numbers or in bytes each (5*10^6 files or files a 5*10^6 bytes)

Comment: Trivial FTP (protocol) made for its simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

A distributed filesystem or use `crontab` to perform an `scp`/`rsync` job.

scp = secure remote copy, you will need to setup identity file and authentication key for key authentication i.e without password

crontab job:

```
crontab -e
```

insert this into the file (for ):

```
*/10 * * * * scp me@remote.machine:/remote/path/file /save/to/path
```

IF everything is harder than a ftp, then use a USB thumb stick!!!

Comment: "simpler" ... and you propose "distributed filesystem"? AND / OR "scp" and "rsync"? really? :)

Comment: in terms of hassle free, it is easier.

Comment: crontab with scp and pre-sharedkey would be one of the simplest setup and very low maintenance

Comment: @Sibster: crontab with ftp is as simple as scp.

Comment: @akira, ftp servers have a long history of vulnerabilities, and all linux servers have/need ssh, few need ftp so why install another possible attack vector

Comment: "Every five minutes" can also simply be achieved by `*/5` instead of manually writing out all the minute values.

Comment: @Sibster: ah, thank you, never understood that...

Comment: @akira ftp isn't scriptable (there are clients that are, but the default one is not), I think, and ftp daemons aren't necessarily set up to expose the directory you want to put it in by default.

Comment: @Random832: transfering files -> no need for remote-scripting (on the server). sshd is not scriptable as well, the shell running on the other side is. automatic remote-login with ftp is as simple / scriptable as it is with ssh. i dont see your point at all.

Comment: @akira my point was that - unlike scp or rsync - the ftp client can't be told non-interactively what file to download. Unless you resort to a hack like sending it commands in a pipe, which is beyond what a crontab one-liner can do.

Comment: @Random832: so many options to log into the remote machine and push or fetch files with just one command, without any user interaction, using ftp: a shell-script, curl, ncftp, wget, wput, the native freebsd-ftp client supports  user:pw@host ... even one of the linux variants supports the use of .netrc (think .ssh/config), quoting the manpage "If auto-login is enabled, ftp will check the .netrc  file in the user's home directory for an entry describing an account on the remote machine" ...

Answer (score 1):

`netcat` is simpler since it is just raw bytes (ala `cat`) over the wire. but you would need a listening `netcat`on the other side as well .. "at the right time" :)

```
receiver> nc -l -s 0.0.0.0 -p 12345
```

and then you send the file via

```
sender> nc receiver 12345 < file
```

this is the most simple way of transfering files from one machine onto the other. no authentification, no encrytion, nothing but raw bytes.

but i won't recommend this in any way  to reliably transfer files over the net. use ssh/scp.

Answer (score 1):

I would say `rsync` is the way to go.

Much easier to script the xfer than ftp can be, and quite smart about how it works (resuming, diffs, etc).  You can also set it up to periodically scan the directory itself, and upload the new/changed files, so you can skip a crontab.

Normally rsync is slient, so if you want to see what it is doing the you need

A fairly nice overview/tutorial: http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/

```
(copy recursively, keep symlinks/users, verbose, checksum)
rsync --progress -avz  
       /copy/files/*.tar.gz 
       username@other-server:/destination/folder
```

As for distributed filesystems, that *sounds* complex.  Can you simply mount the same nfs volume on both machines?  If only one is writing, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Just and extension to this, if you use something like http://www.openfiler.com/ you can have it share an NFS to each of your servers and it will handle file locking, so both (all) servers would be allowed read / write access

Answer (score 1):

Do you want it to be automatically?

sshfs is a good way to go if not, just install sshfs and run

```
mkdir /mount/point
sshfs user@server:/remote/path /mount/point
```

and enter your password in the prompt, then the remote path looks like a local dir on your computer. 
Ofcourse you will need to have an ssh-server on the remote end. OpenSSH is a good alternative

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [set up an NFS server](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-server-export.html) on one node and mount it on the other node.

Answer (score 0):

If the transfer is one direction only, you could roll out a simple HTTP server such as `mini-httpd`, publish the files to a directory that `mini-httpd` exposes, and let the destination download them with `wget`.  `mini-httpd` is the first thing that comes to mind when I think of a simple HTTP server, but I'm sure there's simpler ones (can't you technically have a webserver setup with `bash`?  isn't there like a Perl one-liner somewhere that implements a simple webserver?)

If you already have a web server on this host not exposed to the public you could reuse that.

Comment: There's a python one liner for a server I think. I use lighttpd

Comment: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Answer (score 0):

wput is a command-line ftp-client that makes easier uploading files, with just one single command:

```
wput myfile.tar ftp://user:pass@example.com/mydir/
```

Of course, you could do the same from the other side using wget/curl and a web server.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is the `MidnightCommander` (mc). If you grew up with DOS and NortonCommander.

Comment: which part of `mc` is an option? coz it has ftp-integrated?

Comment: I thought of the shell connection in mc. It's true that is has ftp too.